# phpExcel csv2excel float values wrong

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I´m having a csv input file and trying to convert this to an excel file by help of phpexcel.
the conversation works with one fault. Float values are not converted correctly

csv Input

```
1,Aal Albert,0.876,
2,Äsche Elke,0.1752,
3,Bachforelle Barbara; Bachforelle Barnabas,0.4374,
```

ends in excel ()

```
1  Aal Albert  0.88
2  Äsche Elke  0.18
3  Bachforelle Barbara; Bachforelle Barnabas  0.44
```

How can I keep the original float values?

This is the phpexcel snippet for conversation I found here on stackoverflow:

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
ini_set("precision", "15"); 

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('test.csv');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('MyExcelFile.xls');
```

With kind regards,

toni

Comment: The correct value is stored in the cell, but the default number format is 2dp; check the value properly in MS Excel and you'll see that 0.4374 should still be 0.4374 but with default Excel display rounding to 2dp it will appear as 0.44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the cells to "Text" or even just "General".

E.g.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A3')->setValueExplicit('0.876', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Comment: Except you should be treating 0.876 as a float, not telling PHPEXcel to treat it as a string; and just set the number format mask for the cell to an appropriate number of decimals

Comment: But in the answer, there are a variable number of decimal places, so setting it as a string should avoid having to programatically calculate the number of decimal places before formatting it as a float.

Comment: OK, I apologise for correcting you - I don't know enough about PHPExcel to know any better

Comment: Don't worry about it, it would just mean an extra couple of lines of code :) And under normal circumstances (such as MS Excel on Windows), I would completely agree with you!

Comment: Dom, thanks for your reply. Is there a way to tell phpExcel to thread all input as string? Thus as I don´t see a way to loop through each cell. Pseudo-Code: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getAllCells('')->setValue(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);

Comment: Perhaps we should ask PHPExcel's developers to get rid of datatyping completely, and just cast everything to a string automatically; it would probably simplify the codebase a lot, and might make it faster

Comment: @tBook - You might be able to do `->getCell('A1:AZ100')`, which would 'theoretically' select a large cell range for formatting? Not tested thought so not 100% sure.

Comment: The way to force PHPExcel to cast to string automatically would be to write your own value binder, and use that instead of the default value binder